# Yii2 Dynamic Form Select2 issue - Cloning Twice sub items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Hi In the yii2 dynamic form I am using select2. after using select2 widget it is showing errors as

> yii2-dynamic-form.js:202 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

-- I resolved this error using google. **solution** in dynamic.js file

```
if(typeof widgetsOptions[i] !== 'undefined'){           
                   identifiers[i] = $elem.closest(widgetsOptions[i].widgetItem).index();  
}
```

after it is working fine with the first element. once you click on the (+) button it is showing another error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initSelect2Loading is not defined

in dynamic.js file I resolved this using following **solution**

`initSelect2Loading -> initS2Loading
initSelect2DropStyle -> initS2Open`

after select2 is loading perfectly but the problem is if i click (+) button it is cloning the sub items two times that is is my issue.

screen shot of my screen

[image]